# Publishing SNS message from lambda (node js) result in timeout error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I have used a very simple code slightly modified from AWS provided example:

```js
    exports.handler = async (event) => {
        // Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
        var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
        // Set region
        AWS.config.update({region: 'ap-southeast-2'});
    
        // Create publish parameters
        var params = {
            Message: 'This is a sample message',
            Subject: 'Test SNS From Lambda',
            TopicArn: 'arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-2:577913011449:TestTopic'
        };
    
        // Create promise and SNS service object
        var publishTextPromise = new AWS.SNS().publish(params).promise();
    
        let response = {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
        };
    
        // Handle promise's fulfilled/rejected states
        publishTextPromise.then(
            function(data) {
                console.log("Message ${params.Message} send sent to the topic ${params.TopicArn}");
                console.log("MessageID is " + data.MessageId);
                response.result = 'Success';
            }).catch(
                function(err) {
                console.error(err, err.stack);
                response.result = 'Error';
            });
    
        
        return response;
    };
```

And I am getting a timeout error when testing this service. 3 seconds is the limit.

Since this is a very simply process, I suppose it shouldn't take more than 3 seconds to execute.

I have checked my IAM setting and grant my profile (admin profile) to have full access to SNS service. But the error still persists. I am wondering what is being wrong here and how should I fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am not sure why you're getting the timeout, but your code isn't supposed to work the way you might expect.

See that you're returning your response outside your `.then()` code, meaning that your code is going to return before your `.then()` code is even run (Promises are asynchronous).

Since you're already using Node 8, you're better off using [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await) instead of using the old `.then().catch()` approach.

I have refactored your code a little bit and it works just fine. I have kept the original parameters for your convenience. See how the code is much easier to read and debug.

```js
    'use strict';
    
    // Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
    const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    // Set region
    AWS.config.update({region: 'ap-southeast-2'});
    
    const sns = new AWS.SNS()
    
    module.exports.handler = async (event) => {
    
      const params = {
        Message: 'This is a sample message',
        Subject: 'Test SNS From Lambda',
        TopicArn: 'arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-2:577913011449:TestTopic'
      };
    
      let response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
      };
      try {
        const data = await sns.publish(params).promise();
        response.messageId = data.MessageId,
        response.result = 'Success'
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.stack)
        response.result = 'Error'
      }
      return response
    
    };
```

If for whatever reason you don't want to use async/await, you then need to move the return of your function inside your .then() code, as well as return as soon as the promise is invoked, like this:

```js
    'use strict';
    
    // Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
    var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    // Set region
    AWS.config.update({region: 'ap-southeast-2''});
    
    // Create publish parameters
    var params = {
        Message: 'This is a sample message',
        Subject: 'Test SNS From Lambda',
        TopicArn: 'arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-2:577913011449:TestTopic'
    };
    
    module.exports.handler = async (event) => {
      
      // Create promise and SNS service object
      var publishTextPromise = new AWS.SNS().publish(params).promise();
    
      let response = {
          statusCode: 200,
          body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
      };
    
      // Handle promise's fulfilled/rejected states
      return publishTextPromise.then(
          function(data) {
              console.log("Message ${params.Message} send sent to the topic ${params.TopicArn}");
              console.log("MessageID is " + data.MessageId);
              response.result = 'Success';
              return response;
          }).catch(
              function(err) {
              console.error(err, err.stack);
              response.result = 'Error';
              return response
          });
    
    };
```

I highly recommend you go with approach #1 though.